# Looking for a third party application that would create restore point and triggers it in every boot up

Tags: windows-backup

I am looking for a thrid party restore point application (preferbly free ones) that enables to restore back to it's original point in every bootup. 
I am managing the environment where many annonimus people would use the public workstations, so I need these workstations to be restored every time when the computer reboots. 
If you can suggest any, please let me know. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Windows?  For 32-bit XP/Vista, Microsoft's SteadyState will do what you want for free (though it's only available to download until Dec 31, 2010, so hurry up!  :-) ).  Other (commercial) options are Deep Freeze and Fortres.

You should be able to use that information as a starting point to find other possible competitors.  That's just what I've heard of over the years.

One thing to be careful of: Most of these products will allow the system to be modified while it is booted, they just clear out any modifications on reboot.  A malicious user could theoretically come in at the start of the day, infect the system, and leave it running for others to use all day.  You'll need other procedures to mitigate these kind of attacks if they're a concern.  It's more problematic if these kiosks are unattended.  Even a user-mode keylogger could send a day's worth of user info out onto the internet.